# How to programmatically make a cube cocos3d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

```
CC3BoundingBox bounds = makeBounds(9.5, 5.0, 4.0, 0, 0, 0);
CC3MeshNode *cube = [[CC3MeshNode alloc] init];
[cube populateAsSolidBox:bounds];
```

I have tried this but populateAsSolidBox:
no longer exists. How can I programmatically create a simple box or cube in the latest cocos3d?

Answer (score 1):

populateAsSolidBox: exists in cocos 0.7.1 and 0.7.2

Please reference [cocos3d's document](http://brenwill.com/docs/cocos3d/0.7.2/api/interface_c_c3_mesh_node.html#a1ea6896b09a8a424b09452283b8b6702)

by the way, did you #import "CC3ParametricMeshNodes.h"?

you need ensure that correct headers are included.